# Merging files on AWS S3 (Using Apache Camel)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have some files that are being uploaded to S3 and processed for some Redshift task. After that task is complete these files need to be merged. Currently I am deleting these files and uploading merged files again.
These eats up a lot of bandwidth. Is there any way the files can be merged directly on S3?

I am using Apache Camel for routing.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

S3 allows you to use an S3 file URI as the source for a copy operation. Combined with S3's Multi-Part Upload API, you can supply several S3 object URI's [as the sources keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/CopyPartRequest.html#setSourceKey(java.lang.String)) for a multi-part upload.

However, the devil is in the details. S3's multi-part upload API has a minimum file part size of 5MB. Thus, if any file in the series of files under concatenation is < 5MB, it will fail.

However, you can work around this by exploiting the loop hole which allows the final upload piece to be < 5MB (allowed because this happens in the real world when uploading remainder pieces).

My production code does this by:

1. Interrogating the manifest of files to be uploaded
2. If first part is
   under 5MB, download pieces* and buffer to disk until 5MB is buffered.
3. Append parts sequentially until file concatenation complete
4. If a non-terminus file is < 5MB, append it, then finish the upload and create a new upload and continue.

Finally, there is a bug in the S3 API. The ETag (which is really any MD5 file checksum on S3, is not properly recalculated at the completion of a multi-part upload. To fix this, copy the fine on completion. If you use a temp location during concatenation, this will be resolved on the final copy operation.

`*` Note that you can download a [byte range of a file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GetObjectRequest.html#setRange(long,%20long)). This way, if part 1 is 10K, and part 2 is 5GB, you only need to read in 5110K to get meet the 5MB size needed to continue.

`**` You could also have a 5MB block of zeros on S3 and use it as your default starting piece. Then, when the upload is complete, do a file copy using byte range of `5MB+1 to EOF-1`

P.S. When I have time to make a Gist of this code I'll post the link here.

Comment: This is a really great answer! I am going to be implementing it to dynamically create zip files like is mentioned in [this blog post](http://www.w2lessons.com/2012/01/fast-zipping-in-amazon-s3.html). I am also considering creating a worker pool with AWS Lambda to process the request more quickly by avoiding S3 rate limiting.

Comment: @MadMod I'm not sure the Zip format allows this via direct concatenating of zip files. You'll at least need to update the size and CRC headers of the existing zip after concatenating.

Comment: @JosephLust, any chance you can share Gist?

Comment: @JosephLust Won't the byte reading ultimately result in the utilisation of server resources (where your code is running)? I mean to say, seems like the code would "get data" from the source files and upload in pieces to S3.  If that is so, the thing remains the same. The bandwidth is being used. Can you please confirm once.

Comment: @SumitSrivastava we're gluing together multiple GB of files, so reading in a few MB isn't much overhead. However, you can use a starter object in S3 (i.e. 4.99MB of 0's), and append to that. When you're done building the object, you make a S3 copy request, using the byte range 4.99MB-END and the cuts off the starter object and leaves just the concatenated file.

Comment: @JosephLust Is the Gist available somewhere? Thanks a ton!

Comment: @JosephLust is the git available, I need it to solve our projects problem, which is same as you mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [Multipart Upload with Copy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadUploadPartCopy.html) to merge objects on S3 without downloading and uploading them again.

You can find some examples in Java, .NET or with the REST API [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjctsMPUapi.html).