# Merge/Aggregate S3 Objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have log files being uploaded to S3 from different machines (m1_log.txt, m2_log.txt, m3_log.txt).

They upload to a bucket, but I would like to be able to create log.txt that is the concat of all three.

I was going to write a script that would download all the files, concat them, upload them, and then delete the old ones, but it seems like that's a lot of wasted bandwidth and time.

Is there a way to either:

1. "Append" to files on S3? So we could have each of the processes append to the same log.txt
2. Run a command on s3 every x minutes that would merge them together?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging files on AWS S3 (Using Apache Camel)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290103/merging-files-on-aws-s3-using-apache-camel)

Answer (score 0):

Your first idea, to download them all, concat, upload and delete is the only way to accomplish this task. You can't "append files" or "run commands" on S3.

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered here: [Merging files on AWS S3 (Using Apache Camel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290103/merging-files-on-aws-s3-using-apache-camel)

It is possible to merge files if they're bigger than 5Mb  or if they're not you can fake it out so they are bigger than 5Mb.  this is done through the copy_part command available in most of the aws sdks.  The danilop and Joseph Lust answers are correct

Comment: Please do not post links to [duplicate answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/206345). Instead, consider other actions that could help future users find the answer they need, as described in the linked post.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I didn't realize that option was available.