# How to create one glacier archive for many s3 objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

One of our client asks to get all the video that they uploaded to the system. The files are stored at s3. Client expect to get one link that will download archive with all the videos.

Is there a way to create such an archive without downloading files archiving it and uploading back to aws?

So far I didn't find the solution.

Is it possible to do it with glacier, or move the files to folder and expose it?

Comment: Glacier won't help you create a single archive for your client. If you have a lot of files on S3, such that downloading zipping and uploading will take an excessive amount of time, perhaps you can talk to them about alternatives such as using the AWS CLI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you **can't create a zip-like archives from existing objects** directly on S3. Similarly you can't transfer them to Glacier to do this. Glacier is not going to produce a single zip or rar (or any time of) archive from multiple s3 objects for you.

Instead, you have to **download** them first, zip or rar (or use which ever archiving format you prefer), and the re-upload to S3. Then you can share the zip/rar with your customers.

There is also [a possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19327086/248823) of using multi-part AWS API to merge S3 objects without downloading them. But this requires programming custom solution to merge objects (not creating zip/rar-type archives).

Comment: Spinning up an EC2 instance to do this work would be a good idea, as it won't be charged for moving the data (and almost certainly has higher bandwidth to S3).

Comment: @kdgregory I think its a good way to address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a glacier archive for a specific prefix (what you see as a subfolder) by using AWS lifecycle rules to perform this action.

More information available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html).

**Original answer**

There is no native way to be able to retrieve all objects as an archive via S3.

S3 simply exposes all objects as they are uploaded, unfortunately you will need to perform the archiving as a separate process afterwards.

Comment: But what about glacier?

Comment: Glacier creates an archive for your objects, this is targeted at long term backups with the objects moved from S3 and stored in here instead. You will need to pay a price to retrieve the archive.

Comment: It is not a problem, the question is if it is possible to create one glacier archive out of multiple s3 files, or one folder?

Comment: Right, updated answer you can use a specific prefix to migrate. A glacier archive can hold multiple files

Comment: How does this answer the question of providing an archive to the OP's client? Not only that, but if they followed your advice and moved all their files into Glacier, they'd have a possibly large bill to restore them.